# Isomorphisms preserve cyclic

Tags: group-isomorphism

Is it true that if an isomorphism $f$ maps a cyclic group $G$ to group $H$ that $H$ must also be cyclic?  It seems intuitive but until I can actually prove it I'm always a bit dubious to believe it.

Comment: Hint: Consider a generator for $G$ and what its image generates in $H$.

Comment: It is true, the proof amounts to showing that $H$ must be cyclic as a consequence of the operation preserving nature of the isomorphism. (In symbols: $\phi (x\star y)=\phi (x)\circ\phi (y)$.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Suppose $G$ is cyclic and $\phi: G\to H$ is surjective. Let $G$ be generated by $a\in G$, i.e. $G = \langle a\rangle$. Let $b\in H$. Then there exists some $x\in G$ so that $b = \phi(x)$, as $\phi$ is surjective. Further, since $G$ is cyclic, we have $x = a^n$ for some $n$. Then $b = \phi(x) = \phi(a^n) =\phi(a)^n$. This can be done for any element of $H$, so we see that $H = \langle \phi(a) \rangle$.

Comment: Note that you did not use the fact that $\phi$ is one-to-one, hence it is sufficient that $\phi$ be a surjective homomorphism (rather than an isomorphism), and in this case, $G$ being cyclic implies that $H\simeq\phi(G)$ is cyclic.

Comment: is $\phi(a^{n}) = (\phi(a))^{n}$ true in general?

Comment: @PiccolMan For homomorphisms, yes. If $n = 0$ this is obvious, and if $\phi(a^n) = \phi(a)^n$ for some $n$, then $\phi(a^{n+1}) = \phi(a^na) = \phi(a^n)\phi(a) = \phi(a)^n\phi(a) = \phi(a)^{n+1}$.

Answer (score 2):

To give a direct proof: Let $y\in H$, and $\phi:G\rightarrow H$ an isomorphism of the groups $G$ and $H$. Consider $\phi^{-1}(y)\in G$. Since $G$ is cyclic, we can express $\phi^{-1}(y)$ in terms of a generator for $G$ ($G$ can be generated by a single non-identity element because it is cyclic; why?). Hence we have a generator $g$ for the group $G$ (that is, $\langle g\rangle=G$), and it follows that $\phi^{-1}(y)=g^k$ for some integer exponent $k$. Now we claim that $\phi (g)$ must be a generator for $H$, for every element of $G$ is of the form $g^k$ for some integer $k$. Moreover, because $\phi$ is a bijection, it follows $y=\phi(g^k)$. Now because $\phi$ is an isomorphism, we have that $\phi (g^k)=[\phi (g)]^k$, and thus we have expressed $y$ in terms of a single generator and since $y$ was arbitrary, it follows that $H$ is generated by a single element, and hence must be cyclic.